# SQL Studio Management Studio Import/Export wizard crashes when attempting to import a flat file

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm having a strange issue with users who try to import a flat file into an SQL database. It happens immediately when they click *Import Flat File*, they never actually get into the Wizard. (right-click database -> *Tasks* -> *Import Flat File*). It only happens on a few databases, out of about 50 on the entire server.  It's my understanding that there isn't a specific permission for users to use the Import/Export wizard, they just need datareader/datawriter on the database (they have DBOwner so I know that's not the issue).

I have tried repairing .NET, uninstalling .NET and reinstalling it to no avail. They are on the latest SSMS version possible.

System Information:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17289.0
  Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    14.0.1016.283
  Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     10.0.15063.0
  Microsoft MSXML                             3.0 6.0
  Microsoft Internet Explorer                 9.11.15063.0
  Microsoft .NET Framework                    4.0.30319.42000
  Operating System                            6.3.15063

This is the error message from event viewer as SSMS does not give any specific error details.

```
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2017.140.17289.0, time stamp: 0x5befcf0a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.15063.1266, time stamp: 0x51a816a7
Exception code:0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000f0372
Faulting process id: 0x3674
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4e67aeb7af5c3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 9581ba4f-f461-4ef2-a85d-38468d9e5d50
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Do the flat files they are trying to import exist on their computer's drive, or on a network drive/share?  Do they have write access to that file/folder?  If one of the users logs into a different computer, and tries it from there, do they get the same error(s)?

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff Lohr....On a DB that the wizard works on, when it starts up select either Previous or Introduction in the left-hand pane and you can move back to the splash screen. Un-check the "do not show this screen". Once you have the splash screen enabled, visit one of the Database that are not working and see if it generates an error message instead of an app restart. At least you'll get a better error message. e.g.

[Example Error Popup: DefaultSchema Property not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3RT3.png)